# Use of "Some" when referring to quantities

Tags: adverbs

In journalistic and quasi-academic writing, I've recently noticed an increasing tendency to use "some" as an adverb when referring to quantities.

For example in the sentence:

> "In Indonesia, fish accounts for more than 50% of total protein intake
>   and the fishing industry employs **some 12 million people**."

Is this good style? To my ear it grates. Why can't the writer just say "...employs 12 million people"?

Comment: It's a marker of inexactness; think of it as being short for "something like 12 million people".

Comment: Get over your fussiness. This is standard journalese.

Answer (score 2):

> "...the fishing industry employs *some* 12 million people."

is perfectly grammatical. It is surely how one uses the word 'some' to say 'approximately'.

However, I similarly sense a strangeness to the usage of this *slightly off-brand* version of 'some'. I can't quite place the exact style it is common to but it reminds me slightly of children's literature. There are other adjectives that I could associate with this: 'but', 'certain'

> "I have *but* one life to live"

where 'but' means 'only'.

> "She has a *certain* 'je ne sais quoi' "

where 'certain' means 'particular'

These all sound like strange, not exactly misuses, but a bit outside of the normal meaning of the word with no obvious metaphor.

But style is often opinionated. So I can't really say the choice is wrong. The New Yorker's insistence on avoiding split infinitives often gives ungainly sentences, and sticking with the split would undoubtedly give a more felicitous reading, but hey, they're the New Yorker, and it's their stuff. I can only complain.